# Данные GET запроса с Winhttp отличаются от браузерного

Tags: javascript, html, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста:
-Делаю Get запрос с помощью Winhttp, получаю ответ, и вроде бы все нормально, но...
-Открываю браузер ту же страницу в Chrom`е, и смотрю в "инструменте разработчика", что пришло, а пришло намного больше.

И я не могу понять, как браузер это делает, хотя Chrome также отправляет Get запрос, но сервер ему возвращает больше данных.
Структура сайта такая: есть сам html, а внутри него есть область, которая обновляется без обновления html. И вот мне приходит только HTML, а браузеру еще и текст внутри этой "динамической" области.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую строну копать, никак не могу додумается.

Comment: Alexey Ten, но, когда я смотрел в браузере этапы запроса - вся информация внутри это области была именно в hml при первом GET запросе гугл хрома.

Comment: Ну тогда ищите разницу. Скорее всего разница в куках

Comment: Alexey Ten, подскажите пожалуйста, что значит разница в куках ? Разница в данных, именно в тех данных, которые находятся внутри области, гугл хром их как то получает в первом Get запросе, но в моем Get запросе приходит только html/